# Getting a form get parameter

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble reading the business_id parameter from a form get request.

http://localhost:3000/clients?utf8=%E2%9C%93&client%5Bbusiness_id%5D=toyota&commit=Save+Client

With: params[:business_id]

**Why doesn't that work?**

Details:

**html form:**

```
<%= form_for :client, url:clients_path, method: :get do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :business_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :business_id %>
   <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

The form hits the **create controller** and redirects back to the original page:

```
def create
    @clients = Client.all
    redirect_to controller: 'clients'
end
```

On the original page reads the url string in the **index controller** with:

```
def index
    @clients = Client.all
    @filters = params[:business_id]
end
```

@filters comes back as blank unless I hard code a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `params[:client][:business_id]` as `business_id` is inside `client` hash.

Comment: Worked, thank you. Is there a good way to get that form to pass a regular string like http://localhost:3000/clients?business_id=2 and hit a custom controller instead of create?

Comment: @HoosierCoder Please ask another question explaining in detail.